# Visual Studio Encounters 403 Error Connecting to DevOps Project

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, http-status-code-403

One of my developers is receiving the following message from Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise when trying to connect to one of our DevOps projects and we've tried everything we can think of and everything we've found from searching Stack Overflow and the internet in general just hasn't worked.

Here's the error from Visual Studio:

```
We could not add the account
The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason:
The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
```

What we've tried

1. Deleting the folders Team Foundation, VisualStudio, VisualStudio Services, VSCommon, and vshub located in %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft
2. Deleting everything from Windows Credential Manager.
3. Authenticating via browser (success).

Repository is hosted on dev.azure.com.

From what I understand, this is an HTTP 403 error which means the user successfully authenticated and that they just don't have permissions to view the requested resource. Permissions in DevOps are identical to other users that don't have any issues. We have 1 group for the developers and if you're in that group, you have all necessary permissions so I'm confident their permissions are identical to the other devs that aren't having any issues.

I think I understand what this error means for websites in general, however I seem to be at a loss for what either Visual Studio or Azure DevOps wants us to do specifically to alleviate this error.

Comment: Do your company use AAD in Azure Devops Service?

Comment: We do, yes, and I should add that they were able to authenticate from Visual Studio via AAD account prior to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete.

Once it was a known issue in old VS2015 and VS2017, but I can't reproduce it on my latest VS2017 15.9.23. Here're some tips you can follow to resolve that issue:

1.Update VS2017 to latest 15.9.23 version.

2.Navigate to VS installation path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\VsEdition\Common7\IDE` and run `devenv.exe /resetsettings` and `devenv.exe /resetuserdata` to reset the VS settings and userdata. From [Joyce Lin](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6516141-894e-468c-b8a0-aefdeaf62bd8/i-cant-login-to-visual-studio-community-2017?forum=vssetup).

3.Check your registry settings and empty the China endpoint if it exists. Check [this one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/10021/view.html). Now try to log in the VS...

4.If the issue persists after #3, you can:

```
Open Visual Studio
Click Help > Send Feedback > Report a problem
An instance of Visual Studio Feedback will open
Attempt to sign in using your MS account
If sign in is successful, check if you are signed into Visual Studio
```

Hint from [Nathan Timblin](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/70625/view.html).

Hope all above helps :)

Comment: This solved the problem for us, thank you! Specifically #2 by running devenv /resetsettings and /resetuserdata.